# Capture referer in httpd access logs after a ReWriteRule

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, awstats

We have two domains and one is primarily for marketing purposes to see how our campaigning works. The marketing domain is redirected to the primary domain. In the httpd.conf, we have a virtual host defined for each of the domain that we host and here is how we redirect the marketing domain to primary domain:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
.....
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ http://primarydomain.com/products [L,R=301]
</VirtualHost>
```

The redirection works fine, but in the access log, the "referer" is blank. We use AWStats to analyse our web traffic by looking at the access log and without the referer it is hard for us to say how many people landed on the primary domain through the marking domain link. Any recommendations on how to get the "referer" information passed in as part of the RewriteRule so that it is recorded in the access log?

Thanks!